# Parameter pass in linphone ios outgoing call

Tags: ios, linphone

I want to send parameter in outgoing call. Then I will get the parameters in incoming call for another user. How and where it's possible to make.

Comment: @MidhunMP : why . Can you please explain? or i need to video cal straightly is it possible?

Comment: You can only get the notification of incoming call. You can't handle incoming call via your app. How can you send a parameter over cellular network ?

Comment: that's right…the actions taken for incoming calls are considered to be private api under apple

Comment: @MidhunMP : correct  i'm want to customizing the ios linphone. we can set anything (like parameter notification? Because i want video call  straightly . But now user once attend the voice then only user can enable video . But I'm ending I will give one video call button it will call  straightly video it is possible?

Comment: @user2277872 it is possible?

Comment: idk. If you were to use it, you would be rejected

Comment: @user2277872: how? So it is not possible ah?....

Comment: @MidhunMP: Please answer ya

Comment: because if you have private API inside an application, apple will not allow you to post it on the app store, it is specifically in the rights of apple if you read it

Comment: @user2277872: But linphone is open source. i can change the little ui and other things.

Comment: @2vision2: Not possible as far as I know. If you use private api's apple will reject your app. If you are developing for jail-broken devices maybe you can do this (not sure)

Comment: @Midhun MP: did you use linphone API? where our guys are using. Here also guys are posted question about linphone ios. Just asking question thats all.

Comment: @2vision2: i mean if you use any private api for passing and retreiving parameters or handling incoming calls, then the app will be rejected. I didn't say anything about linphone iOS.

Comment: Reply me back if you haven't got a solution . I might help you.